# Globally Replace The / Character

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiddle - http://codepen.io/mikethedj4/pen/BCJun

[image]

I've been working on a website designer for my tablet and it's almost ready for release, but I have one problem.

You see while I'm adjusting the style properties to get a nice visual style by default the browser adds those css modifications of the element to a style attribute. Which I'm sure most of you are aware of.

I've been able to remove the style attribute by mirroring the whole canvas's html to another div and removing the style in that div so my designing area/canvas still works as intended.

What I'm trying to do is grab this and mirror it into a textarea while grabbing all it's children. Which you can see in my fiddle on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/mikethedj4/pen/BCJun). My question is how can I grab all it's children's css while showing it as seen in the screenshot.

**EDIT**:
I originally tried this, but it would only grab the first element...

```
$('.preview').children().prop("tagName").toLowerCase() + '.' + $('.preview').children().prop("className") + ' {\n ' + 
$('.preview').children().attr('style').replace(/;/g,";\n") + '}'
```

Recently I gave this a try...

```
$('.hidden-preview').html($('.preview').html());
$('.hidden-preview').children("*").html("");
$(".hidden-preview *").removeAttr('contenteditable');
$(".code").val($(".hidden-preview").html().replace(/>/g,'').replace(/</g,'').replace(/style="/g,'{\n ').replace(/class="/g,'.').replace(/"/g,'').replace(/;/g,';\n') + "}\n\n");
```

It seems to work the best, but I can't get rid of the `/` for closing the element in which I'm trying to add the closing css bracket `}`.

Example...

```
.replace(/ //g,'}')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a few modifications:
To get rid of the closing tags' opening bracket:

```
.replace(/<\/?/g,'')
```

the `\/?` is an optional (and escaped) `/`

Use this to extract the style:

```
.replace(/style="([^"]+)"/g,'{\n $1 } ')
```

This captures any non `"` character and reference it by the \1 so `style="foo"` becomes `{\nfoo}`

Lose the replacement for the `"` and the appending of the `}` from the end

(I've actually updated your fiddle)

Comment: This is some interesting JQuery `.replace(/style="([^"]+)"/g,'{\n $1 } ')` I've never needed to use the ^ symbol before. I understand your explanation, but I'm having trouble understanding the `([^"]+)` part mathematically.

Comment: The `^` negates the character class defined by `[]` if it's the first character. So `[^"]` matches any character that is not `"`. So you capturing any number of non quote characters between quotes.

Comment: ok that makes since. It'll take awhile to memorize, but this has definitely been helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`.replace(/ //g,'}')` won't work, cause `/` need to be escaped in regex like that:

```
.replace(/ \//g, '}')
```